# Magento 2.3 : issue in file uploading in backend

Tags: magento2.3.0, vendor, file-uploader

> [2019-03-15 04:50:13] main.CRITICAL: Warning: count(): Parameter must
>   be an array or an object that implements Countable in
>   D:\xampp72\htdocs\mage230\vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php
>   on line 552 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning:
>   count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable in
>   D:\xampp72\htdocs\mage230\vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php
>   on line 552 at
>   D:\xampp72\htdocs\mage230\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
>   []

[image]

**if (is_array($file) && count($file) > 0 && count($file[0]) > 0 && count($file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f3LX.png)) > 0) {**

Replace with

**if (is_array($file) && count($file) > 0 && !empty($file[0]) && (isset($file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f3LX.png)) && !empty($file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f3LX.png)))) {**

[image]

Comment: Did you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you getting the error because the in the **count** function not passing the array so please try to **print $file** as below and check either its printing some data or not.

**Try :**

```
print_r($file);
```

Comment: It is printing data.
but getting error in console  Uncaught ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined

Comment: How can override the Uploader.php file for this fix and add above code @Hiren kadivar